# Gradle: How can I write dependencies into Gradle script?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have a Gradle script with transitive dependencies. How can I write those dependencies into a Gradle script, so that they could be resolved from a flatDir repository?

UPDATED:

We ship our application as a WAR file, and our users should be able to modify and compile code, using WEB-INF\lib folder as flatDir repository. That means that our Gradle build script should generate Gradle script with explicit dependencies.

Comment: Show what you have tried... you should be able to just add them in the `dependencies` block

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why do you need to do this? Also, look into gradle application and distribution plugins, both of these plugins can collect dependencies including transitives into a folder.

Comment: I updated the question, provided context.